# Can Flutter reliably render "0.5"-width lines?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-experience

When designing UX, I find sometimes 0.5-width lines are suitable. For example, `Divider(thickness: 0.5)`.

However, I wonder whether this can be rendered *reliably* in all kinds of devices? For example, will it completely disappear on some kind of devices?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that the line might not be visible on low-density screens.  Try for example to draw a `0.001` line on your device. It will disappear.

By using the `devicePixelRatio` you can prevent the line from becoming smaller than 1px.

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

final pixelPerPoint = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
final onePixelSize = 1 / pixelPerPoint;
return Divider(
  thickness: math.max(0.01, onePixelSize),
);
```

```dart
/// The number of device pixels for each logical pixel. This number might not
/// be a power of two. Indeed, it might not even be an integer. For example,
/// the Nexus 6 has a device pixel ratio of 3.5.
final double devicePixelRatio;
```

Comment: Sounds great, thanks!